# WebView autofill forms

Tags: java, android, android-webview

The forum is a lot of topics dedicated to my question, but all the codes that do not work there.

There is a form:

```
<form name="forma1">
 <input type="text" name="ulogin" size="20" maxlength="50" value="login">
</form>
```

Codes that do not work for me: 
**code 1**

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
   @Override
   public void onPageFinished (WebView webView, String url)
   {
         webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('ulogin').value='"+username+"';");
   }
});
```

**code 2**

```
  String username = "cristian";
webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('ulogin').value = '"+username+"';");
```

**code 3**

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript: {" +
            "document.getElementById('ulogin').value = '"+uname +"';" +
            "var frms = document.getElementsByName('forma1');" +
            "frms[0].submit(); };");
```

But when the page opens, but the form is not filled in, what's the problem?

Comment: The question still relevant((

Comment: OK, just to check - have you enabled JavaScript in the WebView? By default it is off. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setJavaScriptEnabled(boolean)

Comment: WebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
WebView.loadUrl("http://url/");

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions:

1. Check your HTML - you need to set the `id` attribute of the input element to `ulogin`.
2. Generally, I think that `onPageFinished` is the wrong callback to use for this. It means that the network resources have finished loading, not that the DOM elements have been loaded. So when your code runs, the `ulogin` element might not exist yet.
   Can you try to run your script in a JavaScript Interface callback[1] from the HTML document's `onload` event?

[1] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)

Comment: If you are about to add something to the form id, title ulogin, tried it, did not work too.

<input type="text" id="ulogin" name="ulogin" size="20" maxlength="50">

Comment: OK, in that case  I suspect you are running into what I described in issue 2. Can you try my suggestion?

Comment: Can you try to run your script in a JavaScript Interface callback[1] from the HTML document's onload event?

How to do it?

Without onPageFinished does not work.

Comment: Define a new class in Java with a method that will run the WebView.loadUrl() call. Call WebView.addJavaScriptInterface with an instance of that class when you do other WebView related setup. Now in your web page, register an onload listener that calls window.myJSInterface.myMethod(). Where myJSInterface is the name of the interface you set in the call to addJavaScriptInterface, and myMethod is the name of the Java method you want to call.

Comment: Sorry I do not know much java, can write an example for me to understand what you're saying?

Comment: does the tutorial at http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript help?

Comment: No, not helped. there is no such code that I would come in handy. I nuzheno when the page loads for example https://accounts.google.com automatically fills login and password line and enter button was pressed. That is, I load the application, it loads the site itself and comes in the mail, get the type of client.